# proper formatting of initialization vectors in perl using AES CBC

Tags: java, perl, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am trying to decrypt in perl a string that was encrypted in java using AES/CBC.  What I am struggling with is that the encrypted output does not seem to have the initialization vector prepended as the first 16 bytes of the output.  For a proof of concept to verify that my decryption algorithm is working as expected, I would like to hardcode the initialization vector in my perl script.

I am using Crypt::CBC, but when passing the initialization vector to this library, I am not sure what kind of format it is expecting.  I have tried simply passing in the initialization vector as a string, e.g.

```
$my iv = "0000000000000000";
```

but it does not seem to work as decrypting with this initialization vector produces no output.

So my question is, if the initialization vector is created as follows in java:

```
byte[] iv = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
```

how can I replicate this initialization vector in perl?

Comment: The equivalent of the Java IV would be `"\x01\x02\x03\x04..."` or `pack("C*", 1, 2, 3, 4, ...)`

Comment: You shouldn't use a constant IV. That defies the point, resulting in broken security. You should use completely random bytes, and they should be different for each message/stream you encode. Now, it sounds like you're only doing this for testing, in which case you can forget I said anything :)

Comment: @ikegami Oh I absolutely agree.  Unfortunately I do not own the java portion of this code.  I have reached out to the owners as to why the initialization vectors aren't prepended in the output, but in the meantime I have to make do with what I am given.  and Until the iv is prepended I can't make use of a random iv anyway. (note that at least the iv being used is not the one I posted ;) )

Thank you for the formatting I will give that a try!

Comment: sigh. Maybe it'll help to point out the following to them: Not using a *random* iv allows an attacker to prepare an attack offline. Not using a *random* iv allows an attacker to know if two messages are the same without decrypting them. Not using a *random* iv is like not using an iv at all.

Comment: Just to be clear, the two snippets in my first comment are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of the Java IV would be

```perl
my $iv = "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x09\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06";
```

and

```perl
my $iv = pack("C*", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
```

Note that you shouldn't use a constant IV. That defies the point, resulting in broken security. You should use completely random bytes, and they should be different for each message/stream you encode. Now, it sounds like you're only doing this for testing, in which case you can forget I said anything :)

Comment: Well, for CBC mode specifically the IV should be *unpredictable* but close enough I suppose.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes, No, that's not enough. It should also be different for each stream/message. If you don't, encoding the same message twice will produce the same ciphertext, which leaks information to an eavesdropper.

Comment: I think you don't get entirely what *unpredictable* means in cryptography. Unpredictable means that an attacker cannot predict *anything* about the values in the IV. Random values are of course unpredictable, but an encrypted counter is also unpredictable and is used in various protocols as IV for CBC mode.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes A counter is the very definition of predictable. Future iv could be guessed based on past iv

Comment: Don't be rude because I missed a word! I thought you were disagreeing with me because you claimed I didn't know what I was talking about, so I didn't expect you to follow by saying the same thing I was. I fully agree that one should use a random value (e g. like an encrypted counter)  that's what I've been saying since the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps something of following kind will fulfill your requirements

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $vec;

$vec .= chr(rand(255)) for 1..16;

say '0x' . unpack('H*', $vec);
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `rand` for anything relating to security.

Comment: And what you use instead? Some special equipment hash a chip which generates random number.

Comment: There are crpytographic libraries on CPANs that can assist. You can even use `/dev/urandom`

Comment: @ikegami -- `/dev/urandom` is also random number generator. I gave an example how it can be done and it is upto OP which random generator to use. `/dev/urandom` is also not good random number generator. A circuit build around heated resistor gives much better result due thermal noise produced by atoms of heated material and ambient temperature of environment plus electromagnetic field produced by various devices.

Comment: Re "*I gave an example*", Yes, and it's wrong. It isn't safe to use `rand`. /// Re "*`/dev/urandom` is also not good random number generator.*", It's actually a decent one. It is designed with crypto in mind (unlike what you used). `/dev/random` is even better. Why ask a question only to spout misinformation about the answer you receive.

Comment: Custom hardware isn't required for secure communication. You're just being silly now. If the op was interested in more than basic ("consumer-grade") encryption, they wouldn't have asked about basic encryption

Comment: You see, an iv is used in encryption.  For it todo its job, it needs to be random. More random than what `rand` provides.